# Measuring AC power usage

Tags: power

I have a Uni-T UT139C multimeter. I want to measure the power usage of my Blitzwolf USB charger. Can I just connect my multimeter in series with the charger at the wall and measure how much power the charger uses ?

And how can I calculate watts in AC circuits?  it's same as DC (VxI)? Or it is different than that. I searched about it in the internet and it says we need to know the power factor. Is it true?  if so, what is power factor..?

Comment: If your multimeter can measure AC current at the levels the charger is drawing, you can connect it in series, measure the current and multiply by the voltage (all these are *effective* (RMS) values). But if you are not doing it right it will fry your multimeter or its fuse in the best case.

Comment: Yes the multimeter can measure ac current, so if I multiply voltage by the used current I will get the power usage at any given time?

Comment: Well, that won't be a very accurate result, given the load might be  inductive or capacitive, but will give you a close estimate (assuming it is matched such that the power factor is close to 1).

Comment: You will get acceptable close, but your multimeter must be able to measure true RMS and factor in the cos phi between voltage and current. If you really want to measure AC power, get yourself an Voltech PM100 like everyone else.

Comment: It is advertised as true rms multimeter ...

Comment: USB chargers often have a low power factor, so your result is probably going to be off quite a bit. Especially in no load conditions. (I measured some of my chargers and their power factor was around -0.33)

Comment: DMM's will measure AC pk and scale to RMS for a sine wave assumed, but if it is a pulsed current, you will get erroneous high results. but you can get an idea of activity.

Comment: If you are selling the power to the utility, then DIY is out, it needs to be approved by the utility, and installed by an 'approved' person. If you're not selling it but doing it out of the goodness of your heart, then the fact you're asking about metering suggests a level of technical competence that you shouldn't be trying to do it yourself anyway.

Comment: @Neil_UK I am doing this for the purpose of research thank you for your advice.

Comment: Why not buy one? They're not that expensive...

Comment: @peufeu I'm doing this for the purpose of research as I've stated above in the previous comment.

Comment: OK! I thought the research was about solar, not building the meter itself. I've never used these, but AD, ST and others have chips for "energy meter" application, you could start there, I'd bet you'll find app notes with schematics.

Answer (score 3):

> And how can I calculate watts in AC circuits? it's same as DC (VxI)?

Strictly speaking yes it absolutely is. The instantaneous product of voltage and current is power and will have an average value that is true power. Here are a few examples of different types of loads: -

[image]

When the magneta and blue curves multiply you get the red curve (power). The mean of the power waveform is the watts you are billed on.

> I searched about it in the internet and it says we need to know the
>   power factor.

Proper watt meters instantanously multiply voltage and current waveforms to get true average power.

> what is power factor..?

If the true watts are 1000 W and the product of RMS voltage and RMS current is 1000 VA then power factor is unity. If the VA is only 500 then power factor is 0.5.

See my top right diagram - it shows the average power at 50 % of what it is when voltage and current are in phase (top left). If you take the arc cos of 0.5 you get 60 degrees; in other words power factor can tell you how displaced the voltage and current waveforms are.

From this follows the much abused formula that...

Power = V.I.cos (phi)

This implies that if you know the RMS values for voltage and current and, using (say) an oscilloscope, you estimate the phase angle displacement, you can "calculate" watts. Where this gets abused is that more often than not one or both voltage and current waveform shapes are NOT pure sine waves and this can lead to significant errors in power calculation.

No such error is introduced when voltage and current instantaneous waveforms are multiplied together.

Comment: but averaged rms V * averaged rms I is not true rms power if there is an average phase shift

Comment: @tony not even mildly amusing LOL

Answer (score 3):

Alternating current alternates direction (hence the name). A simple Hall sensor on its own won't tell you what's happening.

You would need to calculate power and the sign of the result will tell you direction. This is not a trivial task. See [Open Energy Monitor](http://openenergymonitor.org) for a project that addresses many of the issues you will face. The project includes open hardware and software.

Answer (score 2):

I built a setup that did this, in a very crude way.

Basically I used a current transformer to measure the current, a small centre tapped 6-0-6 transformer to get the voltage as a phase reference then used a diode ring mixer made out of 4001 diodes with the "LO" port driven from the 6-0-6 transformer and the "RF" port driven from the CT to produce DC at the "IF" port  proportional to power and where the polarity depended on power flow direction. A centre zero meter then read the power flow.

It may even be possible to do away with the 6-0-6 transformer, but that leaves you a non isolated circuit which can get exciting, so I preferred to have the isolation.

This works because the power flow depends on the mean value of the VI product, where both V and I are AC, so a mixer and lowpass filter are the obvious way to produce the result.

Do be careful of the fusing, PSC close to the source of supply can be very large and glass fuses have surprisingly small safe interrupt ratings.

Now you should never be backfeeding the grid without using approved equipment as it can be very dangerous for the crews working on the the grid if your gear does not detect grid failure and shutdown. There are extensive rules and standards around this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can only measure the VA draw of the adaptor, not the actual power.

You should be able to measure the supply voltage, and it's not likely to change much over time.  With care to avoid electrocuting yourself, you should also be able to measure the current draw.  Multiply them together and you get the VA figure.

This will not be the true power, as a simple multimeter cannot measure power factor.

For a simple resistive load, the voltage and current will always be in phase, and the VA will equal the true power.

If the appliance is capacitive or inductive (and that includes almost any electronic power supply), then the voltage and current will be out of phase - the peaks of one won't coincide with the peaks of the other.  It's only possible to measure the true power by multiplying together the instantaneous voltage and the instantaneous current at many points over one cycle of the AC waveform.

Answer (score 1):

A better question would have included the unknown meter's specs. !

It appears to support True RMS for ~$50

Yes and no.

### It will not measure power but measure true RMS current or true RMS voltage

- Power requires both to measured simultaneously and scalar multiplied then summed to get a vector power ( Real & Apparent or stored power) This is not done in this meter.

*Be advised not to use this meter for industrial use.  E.g. on a 600Vac busbar as some people have actually burnt to death doing this on other similar meters from lack of arc flash protection.*

Comment: I mostly use it with low voltage DC, rarely use it with 240v ac so, I don't think I wil never use it with 600v...I don't even have access to 600v

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing different about a meter that measures AC power in one direction versus two.  Think about it.  Both the current and voltage go negative and positive over a cycle, even when power is only flowing one way.

To determine power, do lots of measurements of the current and voltage over a cycle.  For each measurement, multiply the two, then apply that product to a low pass filter.  This value is naturally signed, indicating the direction of the overall power transfer.

To avoid aliasing artifacts, both the voltage and current should be sampled at least 100 times, preferably more, per cycle.  Fortunately, this is not hard.  100x the 60 Hz power frequency is only 6 kHz.  With modern microcontrollers, you can easily sample and do the computations at 100 kHz, and still have plenty of processor resources left over for higher level tasks.

Comment: if you could just clarify more how is this value naturally signed, your answer would be complete for me.

Comment: @Billo: You are doing a 4-quadrant multiply.  When the current and voltage are in phase, they will have the same sign, and the result positive.  When they are out of phase, they will have opposite signs, and the result negative.

Comment: Please provide me more info about this "4-quadrant multiplication", the concept is a bit confusing and vague to me, any links or resources would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Billo: Do a couple examples manually and you'll see for yourself.